# avoid windows resizing with wxFormBuilder

Tags: wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

Working with wxFormBuilder under windows 7, Is there any way to set my main wxFrame to a fixed size avoiding resizing?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do it specifically with wxFB, but you need to remove the `wxRESIZE_BORDER` style from your frame. As it is used by default, you may need to explicitly specify the flags you do want to use, e.g. `wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~(wxRESIZE_BORDER | wxMAXIMIZE_BOX)`.

Comment: That has worked very well. Thank you very much.
In wxFormBuilder must be disabled wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE and wxRESIZE_BORDER

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can avoid a wxFrame resizng in wxFormBuilder by simple specifying you frame size in size properties and provide the same frame size in maximum and minimum values, 
that would prevent the window from being resized.

Comment: If this still keeps the default frame style, it's not a good idea as the frame would still look resizeable, confusing the user.

Comment: It not only looks resizeable, but it still is actually, I just tested with wxLua.