# avoid windows resizing with double click

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Related with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956490/avoid-windows-resizing-with-wxformbuilder)

I tried to disable window resizing. So I disabled wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE and wxRESIZE_BORDER options on my wxFrame... and it works.

But now, if user makes a double click over caption bar, the windows is resized again.

How could I avoid windows resizing when user make a double click over caption bar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `wxMAXIMIZE_BOX` style.

---

As per comments, you've been having problems doing this, or perhaps the wxWidgets that you are using does not map through to the underlying window style. If that is the case then you can remove the `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` window style like this:

```
DWORD style = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);
```

Comment: I am not using wxMAXIMIZE_BOX, only wxCAPTION and wxCLOSE_BOX :(

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: I mean if it is Windows, you can use `SetWindowLongPtr` to remove the `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX`. That should be happening anyway with wxWidgets but I have seen a bug report for wxWidgets that says that it does not happen. You could usefully use `GetWindowLongPtr` to find out what window style you window has. Post that here and I'm sure we can track down the issue.

Comment: David, I am using W7, MinGW (gcc 4.8.1) and wxWidgets 2.9.5. Using  SetWindowsLongPtr could help, but now, I dont know how to use it with a window created from wxWidwet using XRC files. Thanks again

Comment: Surely you can get the window handle from the wxWidgets object?

Comment: OK, already got the styles with wxwidget method GetHWND(). Before apply SetWindowLongPtr(wh, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLongPtr(wh, GWL_EXSTYLE) | wxMAXIMIZE_BOX); the style was 256, and after that I get the value 768, but resizes continue with double clicking over caption bar. More ideas?

Comment: Ok, I found that: http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=37461 I must try it, but It looks nice. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Your code is all wrong. You are setting extended window style. But you need to set the window style. And you are mixing up wxWidgets flags with Window style widgets. I'll update the answer to show you what to do.